# How to enable select2 on textarea

Tags: jquery, jquery-select2

I would like to have a select2 tagging in textarea field.

I couldn't find any working solution to wrap select2 on textarea.

When I hooked the select2 on the textarea field I got an select2 input field inside a disabled textarea.

How can I make the whole textarea available for tagging?

Comment: what's you use-case? What are you trying to accomplish?

Answer (score 1):

That's not possible. The supported underlying elements for the select2 control include `input[type="hidden"]` for version 3.5.X and `select` for versions 3.5.X and 4.0.0 (the most recent one as of this writing).

If you want to have all the separate words inside your `textarea` be tags, you need to do something like this:

```
var tags = $("#my-textarea").text().split(" ");
$("#my-select2-element").select2({ tags: tags })
```